# Magento 2: target _blank in navigation links do not work!

Tags: magento2

Anyone know how to get target _blank to work on links in the navigation?

I created a custom mega menu and all links with target _blank do not actually open in a new tab.

I've seen other posts about this, but the files mentioned in those posts do not exist!

Comment: share the html of menu item with "target _blank"